# How does the javac tool process the annotations

Tags: java, javadoc

How does the **javac** tool process the annotations in the source code? Are they compiled and translated into **bytecode** or they will be treated in a way that resembles processing the **comment lines**?

Comment: Define what you mean by "process"? Are you talking about [**compile time annotation processing**](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101)?

Comment: Yes, I mean Compile time annotation processing.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations are handled by the compiler in a special way. They get parsed, but most annotations do not mean anything to the compiler. Some do, for example, if you incorrectly use the `@Override` annotation, a compile-time error will occur. You can find a list of compiler-relevant annotations [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4).

After that, the behavior depends on the annotation type:
If an annotation has its [rentention policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) set to `RUNTIME` or `CLASS`, it will actually be included in the class file. If the retention policy is `RUNTIME`, the annotation can even be accessed at runtime via reflection. Many libraries use this to provide some additional comfort, e.g. JUnit uses `@Test` to mark methods which implement unit tests and looks for those at runtime.

In addition, the java compiler allows to implement so called 'annotation processors', which can access the AST of the compilation unit and process annotations. This is another proof that the compiler does indeed handle annotations.